# Cracks on inner and outer wall

Tags: cracks

as you can see there’s a weird crack on the outer wall and I don’t know how this happened the crack is also on the other side of the inner wall any thoughts what’s causing this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWlfU.png)[image][image]

Comment: Is there any evidence of water leakage from the roof? Water leaking can sometimes cause cracking like that. Otherwise, it could be something to do with framing settling/movement, perhaps something to do with the foundation. Are you in an earthquake zone?

Comment: I’m not in a earthquake zone Someone I know said something about the foundation I’m not sure how it happens